# How do I synchronize input from a microphone array to a PC?

Tags: sound-design, microphone, audio-recording, sound

I'm using 4 microphones to built a microphone array. To interface them with my PC (running Windows), I bought four [USB sound cards](https://www.ebay.com/itm/External-USB-2-0-Virtual-7-1-Channel-3D-Audio-Sound-Card-White-Converter-Adapter/112325559494?epid=9017742712&hash=item1a272004c6:g:Lr4AAOSwfVpYvRTr) and using a [USB hub](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003M0NURK) I connect them to my system. Is there any synchronization problem associated with this setup?? if any, How can I tackle it?

Answer (score 1):

These are not particularly solid interfaces. I would recommend a multi-channel interface rather than four individual interfaces. You would be much more likely to get solid synchronization between all microphones than you would with separate interfaces of this variety.

Comment: Can you please refer such an interface?? Since I couldn't find one with 4 or more than 4 inputs

Comment: http://www.rme-audio.de/en/products/fireface_ufx-plus.php

May I ask what is the application for this array?

Comment: I'm doing a project on sound localization...

Comment: You will probably need condensor microphones with a very low noise floor and definitely a solid device such as the RME, possibly running at higher sampling rates. You are likely to need fairly long cable runs so an interface that uses balanced inputs is likely to be necessary.

Comment: over what sort of distances are you trying to localise sound?

Comment: basically its a gunshot localization system (particularly snipers) just like DARPA created Boomerang.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to achieve this with the sort of architecture you are proposing. My recommendation would be to investigate GPS modules that support accurate timing. GPS will provide the signal synchronization and localization you will need. You will also need omnidirectional condensors with adequate wind protection. You will need to use very wide placement, more than can be achieved with standard microphone cables.

Comment: I'm creating a prototype for a distance of 200 to 250 meters. I'm successfully detected the gunshot but failed to localize it. The program gave artibitary values and then I thought that the problem mighty be with the hardware. BTW how can I use GPS modules in it??

Comment: Alongside localization information, GPS provides a highly accurate high resolution timing signal. You can use this to synchronize the time signals at all your sampling locations. Much easier to then locate signals if the distances are wider.

Comment: Looking at a picture of Boomerang sensors, I would observe that they are using very similar technology to that found in a first-order ambisonic microphone. This will give you direction information, but I would hazard a guess that distance information might be somewhat sketchy. With a widely spaced static array, synchronized by GPS, you would get much better localization information.

Comment: you are providing valuable information. Thanks for it. Please refer such microphones. I'll use them at prototype stage and GPS for main product. And what you say about Vesper microphones VM1000/VM2000 or Acoustic Camera??

Comment: Sorry unfamiliar with Vesper type mics. I work primarily in studio applications. I believe the acoustic camera arrays are coupled with some sort of beam-forming software in order to provide acoustically sourced imaging. Ambisonic mics are fairly common now - Rode NT-SF1 is worth a look.